# Jackson Mapper - how to fail on null or empty values

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, mapper

We're using Jackson JSON mapper in our code to de-serialize some configuration objects. We'd like for Jackson to fail on de-serialization when specific fields are missing or empty

The only feature in Jackson to support this behavior is for primitives :

```
final DeserializationConfig.Feature failOnPremitives = DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES;
```

The thing is the fields in question are mainly strings

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option called: `FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_CREATOR_PARAMETERS`.

So I assume it would be accessible at: `DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_CREATOR_PARAMETERS;`

**Or in `yml`:**

```
jackson:
    serialization:
      indent-output: false
    deserialization:
      fail-on-unknown-properties: true
      fail-on-missing-creator-properties: true
      fail-on-null-creator-properties: true
```

This works on all types, strings, ints, doubles etc..

Comment: Doesn't it work only for properties bound to parameters of  a creator method? I mean a constructor or static factory method.

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin I assume so yes, but that's not really an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered [Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org)?

While Jackson is focused in JSON parsing, Bean Validation is all about declaring and performing validation on your beans.

You could use [`@NotNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) or [`@NotBlank`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotBlank.html) from [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/), the Bean Validation reference implementation.

---

Alternatively you could use [JSON Schema](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema).

Answer (score 0):

Object specific custom Deserializer would have to be created.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Version;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

import java.io.IOException;

class JacksonDeserializerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("CustomPersonDeserializer", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, null, null));
        module.addDeserializer(Person.class, new CustomPersonDeserializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        String jsonString = "{ \"id\": 1, \"name\": \"User 1 \"}";
        Person user = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Person.class);
        System.out.println("User: " + user.toString());

        jsonString = "{ \"id\": 1}";
        user = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Person.class);
    }

    static class CustomPersonDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Person> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4100181951833318756L;

        public CustomPersonDeserializer() {
            this(null);
        }

        public CustomPersonDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
            super(vc);
        }

        @Override
        public Person deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext deserializer) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            Person person = new Person();
            ObjectCodec codec = parser.getCodec();
            JsonNode node = codec.readTree(parser);

            JsonNode idNode = node.get("id");
            int id = idNode.asInt();
            person.setId(id);

            JsonNode nameNode = node.get("name");
            if(nameNode == null){
                throw new IOException("name must be provided");
            }

            String name = nameNode.asText();
            if (name.trim().length() < 1){
                throw new IOException("name can not be empty");
            }

            person.setName(name);
            return person;
        }
    }

    static class Person {
        private int id;
        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", id=" + id +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seriously?! Would you create a _custom deserializer_ for _each class_? What if you had dozens or even hundreds of classes? You won't take _any advantage_ of Jackson capabilities. It's far from being an _acceptable solution_ for a _real project_.

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way:
This works on the objects as well

```
ObjectMapper mapper= new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

Comment: Not different. But it is an alternate way

Comment: This is also default behavior