# Object Mapper to implement not null

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

How to implement below :-
fail if name/id/sal isnull or missing/or has null value then string->pojo should fail.How can i implement ?
Actual json is nested .I have simplifed the json and class structure for brevity.

```
MyClass m = objectMapper.readValue(myClassStringValue, MyClass.class); // fail if name/
public class MyClass
{
    
    @JsonProperty("name")
    @NotNull
     private String name;
   
    @JsonProperty("id")
    @NotNull
     private String id;

    @JsonProperty("sal")
    @NotNull
    private String sal;
    
}
```

Comment: you probably want to use Spring Validation. Example: https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/

Comment: Here is the answer : [Jackson Mapper - how to fail on null or empty values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47326132/14868118)

Answer (score 1):

ObjectMapper objectMapper= new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_CREATOR_PROPERTIES, true);